# List of data is getting null when passing data from view to controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, view

i am new to mvc. i want to send list of data from view to controller. i can pass one employee details but can't pass list . please give some suggestion for sort it out.

Error:-[image]

i need to get the Lidt in controller.

```
  public class EmpDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OldSeq { get; set; }
    public int NewSeq { get; set; }
}
public class DetailsList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<EmpDetails> EmpDetailsList { get; set; }
}
```

In controller have two method get and post. In post method getting id but not list.it is coming as null.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EmployeeDetails()
    {
        List<EmpDetails> c2 = new List<EmpDetails>();
        EmpDetails model = new EmpDetails();


        model = new EmpDetails();
        model.Id = 2;
        model.Name = "Alex";
        model.OldSeq = 4;
        model.NewSeq = 5;
        c2.Add(model);

        DetailsList abc = new DetailsList();
        abc.Id = 1;
        abc.EmpDetailsList = c2;
        return View(abc);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmployeeDetails(DetailsList model)
    {

        return View("EmployeeDetails");
    }
```

In view i'm looping the data and displaying.

```
      @using MvcDemo.Models
      @model  DetailsList

       @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Id)
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model.EmpDetailsList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.OldSeq)
                </td>
                <td>
                     @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.NewSeq)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop. You must use a `for` loop (the property must be `IList<EmpDetails>` or you must use a custom `EditorTemplate` Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for more detail

Comment: thanks for the reply.Could you please explain why i need to use for loop ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks i will look into it

Comment: Refer also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954735/model-binding-with-complex-type/31954778#31954778) for an example of the `EditorFor()` approach

Comment: @nichu09 - this is the way the binding will work by using the `for` loop approach, the generated html will be a match for your model and your `post` will work.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Based on your comment i changed to List and to for loop.it worked. thanks . i will update the correct answer

Comment: @Ric when using for loop , it creating unique id for each control. if i am using for each loop it is not happening, is that the actual problem ? or i missing anything ?

Comment: @nichu09 - try the `foreach` and `for` approach and inspect the html on the page and you will notice the difference.

Comment: @Ric i checked the html . In for each loop control id are same in every row. but in for loop id are different.  Thanks

Comment: exactly! when you visualize it, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use editor templates like this.

1. Create `EditorTemplates` folder in your `Views/Shared` folder.
2. Create a file named `EmpDetails.cshtml` in that folder.
3. Put your foreach markup in that file like

   ```
   @model EmpDetails
   <tr>
       <td>
           @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Id)
       </td>
       <td>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Name)
       </td>
       <td>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.OldSeq)
       </td>
       <td>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.NewSeq)
       </td>
   </tr>
   ```
4. Then replace your `foreach` with a call to `@Html.EditorTemplateFor` method like

   ```
   @using MvcDemo.Models
   @model  DetailsList

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Id)
       <table>
           @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.EmpDetailsList)
       </table>
       <input type="submit" value="Create" />
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ActionResult EmployeeDetails()
    {
        List<EmpDetails> c2 = new List<EmpDetails>();
        EmpDetails model = new EmpDetails();


        model = new EmpDetails();
        model.Id = 2;
        model.Name = "Alex";
        model.OldSeq = 4;
        model.NewSeq = 5;
        c2.Add(model);

        DetailsList abc = new DetailsList();
        abc.Id = 1;
 //  abc.EmpDetailsList = c2;

//change this might help
    abc.EmpDetailsList = new List<EmpDetails>(c2);


        return View(abc);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe adding some detail as to how this answers the question would help.

Comment: try this
 abc.EmpDetailsList =new List<DetailsList>(c2);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply.With the help of @stephen comment , i changed the IEnumerable collection into List. then i used for loop instead of for each. please check the below code.

```
 public class DetailsList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<EmpDetails> EmpDetailsList { get; set; }
}

 <table>
     @for(int item = 0; item < Model.EmpDetailsList.Count;item++ )
     {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.EmpDetailsList[item].Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.EmpDetailsList[item].Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.EmpDetailsList[item].OldSeq)
                </td>
                <td>
                     @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.EmpDetailsList[item].NewSeq)
                </td>

            </tr>
     }
        </table>
```